# Is code posted on stack overflow open source?

Tags: discussion, licensing

I am an iOS Developer and I would like to know if I could use the code found here or the solutions to the problems that users had had in my COMMERCIAL applications freely. Could I do that?

Comment: You might want to re-phrase the title, it reads as if you're asking about the web application that lets us post questions and answers rather than the user-supplied content.

Comment: This is answered in http://stackexchange.com/legal under `3. Subscriber Content`.

Comment: commercial ≠ not open source

Comment: I guess this question would be better suited for META

Comment: FYI, there is a VERY simple solution for your problem: Don't copy&paste code. Look at the proper answer and then write the code based on the answer and/or the code in there.